# Get csv filenames with two keywords

Tags: r

I have a folder with many CSV files. I would like a list of file names containing `Weekly` and `grocery`. The format of the file names is shown below:

```
03_27_2023_Weekly_01_07_2018_grocery.csv
03_27_2023_Weekly_01_14_2018_stationary.csv
03_27_2023_Biweekly_01_07_2018_grocery.csv
03_27_2023_Biweekly_01_21_2018_grocery.csv
03_27_2023_Biweekly_01_07_2018_stationary.csv
03_27_2023_Biweekly_01_21_2018_stationary.csv
```

Below is code that I have used to get all file names containing `grocery`. How do include `Weekly` in the pattern?

```r
list.files(path = path[["files"]],   # path to file folder
           pattern = "_grocery.csv", # pattern that needs to be modified to capture both keywords
           full.names = TRUE)
```

Comment: Try `pattern = "^.*_Weekly_.*_grocery.csv$"`.

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain. How did you do, so I can also learn

Comment: I added the explanation as answer below, and I also forgot to escape the dot in my comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pattern `"^.*_Weekly_.*_grocery\\.csv$"`

- `^` starts with
- `.*` any character between zero and unlimited times followed by
- `_Weekly_` matches the characters `_Weekly_` literally followed by
- `.*` any character between zero and unlimited times followed by
- `_grocery\\.csv` matches the characters `_grocery.csv` literally (the dot needs to be escapped using a double backlash)
- `$` ends with